# Accessing an atomic member of a class held by a shared_ptr

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, atomic

I'm trying to create a small class that will allow me to facilitate a communication between two threads.

Those threads most probably will outlive the context in which the above mentioned class was created as they are queued onto a thread pool.

What I have tried so far ([on coliru as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f0d5bc4556110d2)):

```
class A    
{
public:
    A(int maxVal) : maxValue(maxVal) {}    
    bool IsOverMax() const { return cur >= maxValue; }    
    void Increase() { cur++; }

private:
    const int  maxValue;    
    atomic_int cur{ 0 };
};
```

possible usage:

```
void checking(const shared_ptr<A> counter)
{
    while(!counter->IsOverMax())
    {
        cout<<"Working\n";         // do work
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }
}

void counting(shared_ptr<A> counter)
{
    while (!counter->IsOverMax())
    {
        cout<<"Counting\n";
        counter->Increase(); // does this fall under `...uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(9ms);
    }
}

int main() 
{ 

    unique_ptr<thread> t1Ptr;
    unique_ptr<thread> t2Ptr;

    {
        auto aPtr = make_shared<A>(100); // This might be out of scope before t1 and t2 end
        t1Ptr.reset(new thread(checking, aPtr)); // To simbolize that t1,t2 will outlive the scope in which aPtr was originaly created
        t2Ptr.reset(new thread(counting, aPtr));
    }

    t2Ptr->join();
    t1Ptr->join();
    //cout<< aPtr->IsOverMax();
}
```

The reason I'm concerned is that  the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) says that:

> If multiple threads of execution access the same std::shared_ptr object without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a **non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur** unless all such access is performed through these functions, which are overloads of the corresponding atomic access functions (std::atomic_load, std::atomic_store, etc.)

- So `Increase` is a non const function, are the copies of aPtr are `the same std::shared_ptr` for this context or not ?
- Is this code thread-safe?
- Would this be OK for a non atomic object (say using an std::mutex to lock around reads and writes to a regular int)?
- In any case why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So Increase is a non const function, are the copies of aPtr are the same std::shared_ptr for this context or not ?

At `std::thread` creation, `aPtr` is passed by value. Therefore, it is guaranteed that:

- You don't introduce a data race since each thread gets its own instance of `shared_ptr` (although they manage the same object `A`).
  The documentation you are referring to describes a scenario whereby multiple threads operate on the same `shared_ptr` instance.
  In that case, only const member functions can be called (see below), or synchronization is required.
- `shared_ptr` reference-count is incremented before `aPtr` goes out of scope in `main`

So yes, this is a correct way to use `shared_ptr`.

> Is this code thread-safe?

Your code does not introduce a data race, neither with access to `shared_ptr` instances, nor with access to the managed object `A`.
This means that there are no conflicting, non-atomic, read and write operations to the same memory location performed by multiple threads.

However, keep in mind that, in `checking()`, the call to `IsOverMax()` is separated from the actual work that follows
(`Increase()` could be called by the second thread after `IsOverMax()` but before '*do work*'). Therefore, you could '*do work*' while `cur` has gone over its maximum.
Whether or not that is a problem depends on your specification, but it is called a race condition which is not necessarily a programming error (unlike a data race which causes undefined behavior).

> Would this be OK for a non atomic object (say using an std::mutex to lock around reads and writes to a regular int)?

`cur` can be a regular `int` (non-atomic) if you protect it with a `std::mutex`. The mutex must be locked for both write ***and*** read access in order to prevent a data race.

One remark on calling `const` member functions on objects shared by multiple threads.
The use of `const` alone does not guarantee that no data race is introduced.
In this case, the guarantee applies to `shared_ptr` const member functions, because the documentation says so.
I cannot find in the *C++ standard* whether that guarantee applies to all const member functions in the *Standard Library*

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is talking about the member functions of `shared_ptr`, not the member functions of your class.  Copies of `shared_ptr` objects are different objects.

I believe the code is thread safe, because the only changing variable written and read on different threads is `cur`, and that variable is atomic.

If `cur` was not atomic and access to it in both `Increase()` and `IsOverMax()` was protected by locking a `std::mutex`, that code would also be thread safe.